# Displaying User Full Name instead of User Email in AspNet MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I want to display a full name whenever a user logs in. Currently, I need a customize code that I work with because I am not using the identity method of getting the user logged in username.

Whenever I try using the supplied links, it either returns a null error or it displays nothing after it has logged in.

I have used the following links:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991663/Displaying-User-Full-Name-instead-of-User-Email-in

https://forums.asp.net/t/1848780.aspx?How+to+replace+User+Identity+Name+by+FirstName+Last+Name+at+login+time

```
public class ApplicationBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User != null)
        {
            var context = new mymodel();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.FirstName == username);
                string fullName = string.Concat(new string[] { user.FirstName, " ", user.LastName });
                ViewData.Add("FullName", fullName);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
    public ApplicationBaseController()
    { }
}


  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/Sigin" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
  </authentication>
```

Comment: Your user's username and first name are expected to match each other?

Comment: Yes they are supposed match each other

Comment: So what happens when you have two users named John? Or two Katy's? Do you expect them to go change their legal name? Why did you tag this as both Entity Framework and Linq to Entities? Which is it? Where's your view? You haven't given us a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to at least implement some sort of ID system to reference the users insides what looks to be some sort of User class.

[mason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1139830/mason) explained it well that you will easily run into duplicate names and usernames very quickly. A common way to handle this is to attach an ID to a user. That way you can have multiples of the same name because you are just referencing them with an ID instead.

Your lambda expression would end up looking something like:
`u => u.ID == passedInID`